# CakePHP: How to use a non-default user model for authentication?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi i have a table name `chat_users`

I have connected `users` table for last few projects it working fine. But this is my first project i have a different table name `chat_users`

I want to login this table with `username` and `password`

I have tried but unable to login.

Please help me.

Code-

AppController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Auth', 'Session', 'Email', 'Cookie', 'RequestHandler', 'Custom');
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Cache', 'Session','Custom');

     function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array (
                'scope'  => array('ChatUser.is_active' => 1),
                'fields' => array('ChatUser.username' => 'username', 'ChatUser.password' => 'password'), 
            )
        );        
    }
}
?>
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'Users'; //Controller name
    public $uses = array('ChatUser');
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }
    public function index() {
    }
    public function login() {
        $this->layout='login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if (!$this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'), 'error_message');
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
        }
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.ChatUser')) {
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                exit;
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

Above query i am getting missing table.

See screenshot-

[image]

Comment: Can you please let us know login method called when you do login ? If so then which condition is being executed in login method ? Also,You can refer this [URL](http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/working-with-auth-component-in-cakephp/)

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly! Also when receiving errors, please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your auth component configuration is incorrect. You are missing the appropriate `userModel` option, which defines the name of the model to use

And the `fields` configuration doesn't work the way your are using it, the keys must be named `username` and `password`, and the value can then contain the actual column name, however since your columns are obviously using the default names, there's no need to use this option at all.

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array (
        'scope' => array('ChatUser.is_active' => 1),
        'userModel' => 'ChatUser' 
    )
);
```

Also the session key will always be `Auth.User` unless you are explicitly changing it via `AuthComponent::$sessionKey`:

```
$this->Auth->sessionKey = 'Auth.ChatUser';
```

However, you are better of using the auth component to access the user data anyways:

> ```
> // Use anywhere
> AuthComponent::user('id')
>
> // From inside a controller
> $this->Auth->user('id');
> ```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Authentication > Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)**
- **[Cookbook > Authentication > Accessing the logged in user](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)**

Comment: Hi you told me the keys must be named `username` and `password`. Suppose i have `email` field instead of `username` then what can i do?

Comment: `$this->Auth->user('id');` not working in the view. it will be `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');`

Comment: @chatfun As I said, the actual column names are to be defined as the array values (`'username' => 'email'`). Just read the linked docs, it's all shown there. Of course `$this->Auth->user('id');` won't work in the view, that's why it says "_From inside a controller_". In a view you'd use `AuthComponent::user('id')`, which can be "_used anwhere_", alternatively just pass the values from the controller into the view.